# Accessing individual digits of a BigUint in rust

Tags: rust

I'm just learning rust, henceforth this question has probably some trivial answer.

I want to access to individual digits of a rust BigUint. This is for a project Euler puzzle asking the sum of these digits.

I did it like below:

```
let mut f = func(100);
let mut total: BigUint = Zero::zero();
while f > FromPrimitive::from_uint(0).unwrap() {
    let digit = f % FromPrimitive::from_uint(10).unwrap();
    f = f / FromPrimitive::from_uint(10).unwrap();
    total = total + digit;
}
println!("");
println!("Sum of digits of func(100) = {}", total);
```

It works, but it's quite frustrating, because I believe these digits are internaly stored as an array, but I can't access to them directly because the underlying data member is private.

Is there any way to do that in a more straightforward way ?

Comment: I recently did this by casting to String and iterating through the digits that way.

Comment: @C.Quilley: It may be the right way. I'm wondering if internal BigDigits are actually base 10. If not string output is certainly the way. Would you care to provide an answer ?

Comment: normally I would be happy to, but I'm at work, and as such don't have the source.

Comment: `BigUInt` stores a `Vec<BigDigit>`, and `BigDigit` is an alias for `u32`. The implementation for the `Add` trait, if I understand correctly, uses binary arithmetic and the `BigDigits` are in little-endian order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended doing it using to_string() as suggested by @C.Quilley. But as @Levans pointed out the internal implementation merely perform a div_rem. I still prefer that version because I see it as more readable and straightforwad.

```
extern crate num;
use num::bigint::BigUint;

// What this function does is irrelevant
fn func(n: uint) -> BigUint {
    let p : BigUint = FromPrimitive::from_uint(n).unwrap();
    p*p*p*p*p*p*p*p*p*p*p*p*p
}

fn main() {
    let n = 2014u;
    let f = func(n);
    let total: uint = f.to_string().as_slice().chars()
         .fold(0, |a, b| a + b as uint - '0' as uint);
    println!("Sum of digits of func({}) = {} : {}", n, f, total);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The internal storage of `BigUint` is a vector of `BigDigit`, which is an alias for `u32`, so it probably won't help you a lot to get the sum of base 10 digits.

I doubt casting to `String` would be an efficient way to compute this, but you can make it a little more straightforward using the `div_rem()` method from trait `Integer`. (After all, casting to `String` does this computation internally.)

```
extern crate num;

use std::num::Zero;
use num::bigint::BigUint;
use num::integer::Integer;

fn main() {
    let mut f = func(100);
    let mut total: BigUint = Zero::zero();
    let ten: BigUint = FromPrimitive::from_uint(10).unwrap();
    while f > Zero::zero() {
        let (quotient, remainder) = f.div_rem(&ten);
        f = quotient;
        total = total + remainder;
    }
    println!("");
    println!("Sum of digits of func(100) = {}", total);
}
```

Comment: If casting to String actually does this instead of using some specialized algorithm it's indeed no better. If I understand correctly as div_rem is at best O(n) these implementations will be O(n**2). I was expecting something better from internal conversion to string.

Comment: Well, if you have a number stored in a base that is not `10` and want it in base `10`, you have no choice but to convert it, and this is the algorithm to do it. Check by yourself `BigUint` implementation of `Show`, it does it as well here : http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/num/home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-linux/build/src/libnum/bigint.rs.html#665-678

Comment: It may be the actual implementation (looks indeed so in bigint.rs, but not sure, I'm not yet easy reading rust code). If so it's a naive one likely to be enhanced sometime. Of course you can do it this way, but why would it be the best algorithm ? I would expect some divide and conquer algorithm to be much better. Maybe using some intermediate steps dividing by some power of base to split the number in two parts of approximately same size and recursively doing that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493279/how-can-i-convert-a-very-large-integer-from-one-base-radix-to-another-using-fft

Comment: @kriss feel free to implement it and submit the patch to rust upstream, I think they had no such optimization in mind when writing this code (as I didn't when writing my answer), and they'll probably appreciate it. ;-)